# Difference of tensor product when we change the ring base

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring,  $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. We can prove by definition that $S^{-1}R \otimes_R M \cong S^{-1}M$ as $S^{-1}R$-modules. I have 2 questions:

1) Are those two modules isomorphism as $R$-modules as well?

2) By the exact same proof, isn't that clear that $S^{-1}R \otimes_{S^{-1}R} M \cong S^{-1}M$, too? I mean, all we do is considering the $R$-bilinear that maps $(r/s,m)$ to $rm/s$, which is also a $S^{-1}R$-bilinear, right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Suppose we call the isomorphism $f : S^{-1}R \otimes_R M \to S^{-1}M$. Then for $f$ to be an $R$-module isomorphism, we only need to see that $f(ra) = rf(a)$ for all $r \in R$. Well, how do we define $ra$ and $rf(a)$? We define the $R$-module structure through the map $R \to S^{-1}R$. Thus

$$ f(ra) = f\left( \frac{r}{1} a \right) = \frac{r}{1} f(a) = r f(a). $$

So we see that if $f$ is $S^{-1}R$-linear, then it is $R$-linear.

2) Taking a tensor product over $S^{-1}R$ only makes sense if $M$ is an $S^{-1}R$-module. When that happens, we have obey the rule $A \otimes_{A} M \cong M$. Well, if $M$ is already an $S^{-1}R$-module then $S^{-1}M = M$ so this is okay, but $M$ doesn't necessarily have to be an $S^{-1}R$-module.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, in the 1) part, does it make any difference when we consider the modules as R module and S-1R module? I mean since the proofs are technically the same, is it important?

Comment: @chítrungchâu Consider that the point of constructing $S^{-1}M$ or $S^{-1}R \otimes_R M$ is to create an $S^{-1}R$-module. Moreover, every $S^{-1}R$-module is an $R$-module through the map $R \to S^{-1}R$, but not every $R$-module is an $S^{-1}R$-module. Thus this is a strictly stronger property.